# Understanding the fractional quantum Hall effect in Chern-Simons formalism described in Wen's book

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-field-theory, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

So I study fractional quantum hall effect with Chern-Simons formalism by using Wen's book, this is an excellent book, but it assumes that you know field theory very well thus it has gaps between steps. I try to fill these steps by myself but I have some issues.

So Wen starts  with following equation $$\mathcal{L}=eA_i J^i+KE,PE \tag{1}$$
this makes sense this is just a general Lagrangian with external electromagnetic field applied.  Now we want to get the following equation of motion from this Lagrangian $$-eJ^{\mu}=-\sigma_{xy}\partial_{\nu}A_{\lambda} \tag{2}$$
Now, this is something we did not derive we just want to get this result because it is the electromagnetic response of current to external EM field in Hall system. (I suppose it holds for classical Hall effect as well.) So, we want to make the lagrangian give this solution. Finally, there is one more thing we have to consider; this system should have $U(1)$ gauge invariance and it means that $\partial_{\mu} J^{\mu}=0$. So we write $J$ in form that it automatically satisfies this that is $$J^{\mu}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\partial_{\nu}a_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda} \tag{3}$$

So what I understood is this is just an math trick to make $J$ conserved.

Now we plug this in to the lagrangian which is
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{e}{2\pi}A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}a_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}+KE,PE \tag{4}$$
for the next step, we have to make this Lagrangian obey to the Euler-Lagrange equations. Actually, I am not sure about this step so one of my questions  is it correct what I do here? E-L equations is$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial{a_{\nu}}}=\partial_{\mu}{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial({\partial_{\mu}{a_{\nu}}})}} \tag{5}$$ 
So by equating (2) and (3), we find that in order to $\mathcal{L}$ obey E-L equations it should have the form
$$\mathcal{L}=+m\frac{1}{2\pi}a_\mu\partial_{\nu}a_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}+\frac{e}{2\pi}A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}a_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda} \tag{6}$$
how ever this is not correct according to the book this should be as 
$$\mathcal{L}=-m\frac{1}{4\pi}a_\mu\partial_{\nu}a_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}+\frac{e}{2\pi}A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}a_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda} \tag{7}$$
so there should be an extra $-1/2$ term in front of the first term. So what is my mistake here?

And my second question is in this chapter I see several times this identity $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial{a_{0}}}=0 \tag{8}$$ but this is not consistent with the E-L equations. So  I think I am doing something wrong with the E-L equations. What are my mistakes?

Comment: I'm confused. Euler-Lagrange equations are equations for the field, not the Lagrange density. Also, your last equation is a choice of gauge.

Comment: @RyanThorngren  I don't get your point. I used the equation (4) in the following link. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Lagrangian_formalism_for_fields#Vector_field

Comment: You're trying to derive the Lagrangian from the equation of motion? It doesn't make sense because all Chern-Simons levels give the same equations of motion, namely $da = 0$.

Comment: @RyanThorngren Thorgren Yes I am trying to do that. Because what I understood is Wen is doing that in the book. He says that we choose lagrangian in such a way that it produces the equation of motion (2).

Comment: I see. Once you add $J$ it does become a meaningful question. I think if you do the computation of the equations of motion carefully, by computing the first order variation under $a \mapsto a + \delta a$ and requiring $\delta S = 0$ you will find Wen's Lagrangian given (2) (which needs help with its indices and signs).

Comment: @RyanThorngren so $\delta S=0$ under variation of $a\rightarrow a+\delta a$ gives the euler lagrange equation (5) but when I do that there is a $-1/2$ factor mistake.